# How to add system icons in an imagelist in a listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, imagelist

I have added icons in a `imageList` via using this code in the listview. Now I want them to be displayed whenever the list view of certain directory is shown.

My question is:

What changes would I need to make in `imagelist1` control? And how to call `imagelist1` in the code?

```
imageList1.Images.Add(
    BlackFox.Win32.Icons.IconFromExtensionShell(
        ".*", 
        BlackFox.Win32.Icons.SystemIconSize.Small));

//lv.ImageIndex = 1;
```

Comment: Who is this "BlackFox" guy?

Comment: its a class from which systemicons are retrived.

Comment: when i use it as picturebox.image.add(BlackFox.Win32.Icons.IconFromExtensionShell(
        ".zip", 
        BlackFox.Win32.Icons.SystemIconSize.Small)); it shows the zip icon

Comment: i was wondering if i can add it in same way in an imagelist .and when a list of files is displayed i get the icons with them

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to display the icons in the ImageList together with the corresponding files in the ListView. To do this you only need to point the `SmallImageList` or `LargeImageList` attribute of your ListView object to the ImageList (depending on the icon display mode your ListView uses).

```
private void UpdateListView() {
   ImageList IconList = new ImageList();

   IconList.Images.Add(
        BlackFox.Win32.Icons.IconFromExtensionShell(".*",
        BlackFox.Win32.Icons.SystemIconSize.Small));

   YourListview.SmallImageList = IconList;

   //Add the items to your Listview                

}
```

Don't forget to assign the icons in the ImageList to the items in the ListView:

```
MyListItem.ImageIndex = 0;
```

or

```
MyListItem.ImageKey = "MyImageName";
```

or add them right away when you add your ListItems:

```
ListViewItem MyListItem= new ListViewItem("ItemName", "MyImageName");
ListViewItem MyListItem2= new ListViewItem("ItemName2", int ImageIndex);
```